# Getting a full house with exactly 3 suits represented

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways can you make a full house with only 3 suits represented in the 5 card hand?

My attempt:

1. get the pair first:   $$ {13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}$$
   this allows us to pick any $2$ suits from one of the $13$ ranks.
2. get the triple: $$ {12 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1}^3$$
   this allows us to pick one of the $12$ remaining ranks, but with only 3 possibly suits to choose from.

this equals $$ {13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1}^3 = 25,272$$

where the answer should only be $1872$

Where have I over counted?

Comment: When getting the triple, you need to choose *one* of the two remaining suits to include (and must include the two suits already included).  There are two ways to do that.  So the result is ${{13}\choose{1}} {{4}\choose{2}} {{12}\choose{1}} 2 = 1872$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx when you do C(12,1)*2 doesn't that imply that you are only picking one card from the two possible suits?

Comment: Yes: you *are* picking only one card from the two possible suits.  The other two cards in the three-of-a-kind must have the two previously chosen suits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't $\binom{3}{1}^3$ but rather $\binom{2}{1}$ because you must choose $2$ of the three-of-a-kind to be the suits of the pair, and one of the three-of-a-kind to be a new suit.

Comment: but why isn't it `2^3` since you have to pick 3 cards

Comment: You are restricted in the cards you can choose because you cannot pick both of the other two suits. So $\binom{4}{3}$ overcounts by a factor of exactly $2$.